# lightning:tabClosed event throwing error when calling apex method

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-events, workspaceapi, aura-enabled

I am calling apex method on lightning:tabClosed event to update a record on closing the tab. I can see the record Id being passed to controller method but query is throwing an error saying

```
{"exceptionType":"System.QueryException","isUserDefinedException":false,"message":"List has no rows for assignment to SObject","stackTrace":"Class.AccountViewController.updateCustomerInteraction: line 13, column 1"}
```

Has anyone worked on this kind of functionality before and know why this is happening?

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,lightning:isUrlAddressable" access="global" controller="AccountViewController" >
     <lightning:utilityBarAPI aura:id="Accountbar" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <aura:attribute name="interactionId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="updatedInteractions" type="vlocity_ins__CustomerInteraction__c" />
    <lightning:workspaceAPI aura:id="workspace" />
    <aura:handler event="lightning:tabClosed" action="{! c.onTabClosed }"/> 
    
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    
</aura:component>
```

JSController:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("Tab Focused");
        //SVP-7878 --> START
        var workspaceAPI = component.find("workspace");
        workspaceAPI.getFocusedTabInfo().then(function(response) {
            var focusedTabId = response.tabId;
            component.set("v.interactionId",JSON.stringify(response.pageReference.state.vlocity_ins__interactionId));
            console.log("Interaction ID params: "+component.get("v.interactionId"));
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        //SVP-7878 --> END
        
    },
    
    // SVP-7878 POC /START
    onTabClosed : function(component, event, helper) {
        var currentTabId = event.getParam('tabId');
        //console.log("Tab closed: " +currentTabId);
        var interIDD = component.get('v.interactionId');
        console.log("InteractionId Id in Tab CLosed:: "+interIDD);
        var action = component.get("c.updateCustomerInteraction");
        action.setParams({"interactionId": interIDD});

        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state == "SUCCESS"){
                console.log("IT WORKED!!");
            } else {
                console.log('There was a problem : '+JSON.stringify(response.getError()));
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    } 
    // SVP-7878 POC /END
})
```

APEX CLASS:

```
public without sharing class AccountViewController {
    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static void updateCustomerInteraction(String interactionId){
        system.debug('::UPDATECUSTOMERINTERACTION:: ' +interactionId);
        vlocity_ins__CustomerInteraction__c CI = [SELECT Id, vlocity_ins__Status__c 
                                                   FROM vlocity_ins__CustomerInteraction__c 
                                                   WHERE Id = :interactionId];
        CI.vlocity_ins__Status__c = 'Completed';
        update CI;
    }
}
```

debug statement in the apex class is getting value of interactionId but query is failing.[image]

**UPDATE:**

This is working if i pass recordId in the tabClosed event but not a url param. Though the param Id getting passed to Apex method but SOQL is returning empty.

Answer (score 0):

By default SOQL in salesforce return list of SObjects. But when you try to do this : `vlocity_ins__CustomerInteraction__c CI = [SELECT Id, vlocity_ins__Status__c FROM vlocity_ins__CustomerInteraction__c WHERE Id = :interactionId];`

and when no data is found, it is not able to fetch the first record from the list and it throws an error `List has no rows for assignment to SObject`

Always try to return a list

```
List<vlocity_ins__CustomerInteraction__c> vlocityCustomerInteractions = [SELECT Id, vlocity_ins__Status__c FROM vlocity_ins__CustomerInteraction__c WHERE Id = :interactionId];
if(!vlocityCustomerInteractions.isEmpty()){
    // Then run your logic of updating
}
```

Comment: List is still returning empty.

Comment: then it might be sharing issue for the record.

Comment: I just added an update to my question, please see.